# Algorithm to find a user match on fuzzy @username

Tags: algorithm, comments, fuzzy-search

I'm sure I saw a post on Meta or SO where Jeff posted the upgraded algorithm which matches comments better, for example when someone types a comment:

```
@Tom did you see
```

It will match username 'Tom'.  If there are special characters, say my username is 'T0m' and someone types `@Tom` it still matches.

Does anyone have a link to this post if it does indeed exist?  If I recall correctly it was code he shared, and would be useful for me!

Otherwise, given a list of usernames who are involved in the discussion:

```
users[0] = "Tom"
users[1] = "Peanut"
users[2] = "Ashley"
users[3] = "Jon"
users[4] = "AARÓN"
```

And you are given `@Aaron` or `@Aron` as an input, what's the best way to select the correct user being referred to in the list?

A general algorithm would be fine, but the site I'm doing it for is ASP.net c# so if there's an example in that language it would be brilliant.  This is what I have so far, it works great for EXACT matches (all lowercase):

```
// Find comment references
if (Search.Type != Alerts.SectionType.error)
{
    // A list of all lower case usernames refered to in this thread
    string[] References = Alerts.CommonFunctions.extractReferences(Comment);

    // Only proceed if any references are found
    if (References.Count() > 0)
    {
        // Extract all usernames involved in this comment discussion
        UserBasic[] UsernamesInThread = getAllUsernamesInThread(Anchor);

        // Loop each reference
        foreach (string r in References)
        {
            // Try to find a match
            foreach (UserBasic u in UsernamesInThread)
            {
                // Exact match found
                if (r == u.Username)
                {
                    // Check it's not original author (we can then ignore as alert already issued)
                    if (u.UserID != Search.OriginalAuthorID)
                    {
                        Alerts.CommonFunctions.createAlert(u.UserID, Settings.CommentReplyAlertID, Search.URL, Search.Title);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Don't forget letter spacing - e should match r more than l.

Answer (score 1):

Peter Norvig wrote a beautiful example of a [very small spelling corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) here:

It has two C# implementations listed.

For your specific problem (where the set of candidates is very small), you might want to find the minimal [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between the target word and all of the candidates.